# Retorno de comando SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

Preciso selecionar em meu banco de dados todas as impressoras compatíveis com determinado suprimento selecionado, por exemplo, o suprimento de código **155** que se chama **50FOZ00**. Faço a `query` abaixo para selecionar todas as impressoras compatíveis:

```
SELECT suprimento
      ,modelo
  FROM public.suprimento
      ,public.modelosuprimento
      ,public.impressoramodelo
 WHERE public.suprimento.codigo = public.modelosuprimento.codigosuprimento
   AND public.modelosuprimento.codigomodelo = public.impressoramodelo.codigo
   AND public.suprimento.codigo = 155
```

E o meu retorno esta vindo corretamente, me sendo exibido isso:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

É possível que esse retorno seja exibido de forma diferente? Onde na primeira coluna fica o suprimento e para cada modelo de impressora compatível seja criado uma coluna nova? Ficando algo semelhante a isso:

```
SUPRIMENTO | MODELO | MODELO | MODELO | MODELO | MODELO | MODELO | MODELO | MODELO | MODELO | MODELO |
50FOZ00    | MS310  | MS312  | MS315  | MS410  | MS415  | MS610  | MX310  | MX410  | MX511  | MX611  |
```

Comment: tem um cara chamado [PIVOT](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/tablefunc.html)

Comment: Tu poderia dar um exemplo @MarconcilioSouza??

Comment: Com PIVOT, teria que passar na `query` os codigos do suprimento fixamente, pode ser R.Santos?

Comment: Pode ser, pois futuramente eu precisarei de um parâmetro (codigoSuprimento) para selecionar apenas determinado suprimento

Comment: Tu teria algum exemplo para me dar @David?

Comment: @David, @MarconcilioSouza Eu não poderia utilizar o `group by` para exibir todas as impressoras por suprimento? Eu tentei assim:  `select suprimento, modelo from public.suprimento, public.modelosuprimento, public.impressoramodelo where public.suprimento.codigo = public.modelosuprimento.codigosuprimento
and public.modelosuprimento.codigomodelo = public.impressoramodelo.codigo and public.suprimento.codigo = 155  group by public.suprimento.suprimento` mas deu erro na hora de executar

Comment: @MarconcilioSouza eu estava pesquisando agora o assunto que você sugeriu "PIVOT" porém dessa forma eu não tenho determinar de forma dinâmica as colunas

Comment: @Renan eu não consegui entender o exemplo que você sugeriu como uma possível duplicata, e o autor da pergunta também não selecionou nenhuma das respostas como correta para ele e por esse motivo criei a minha

Comment: Existe um jeito de fazer isso dinamicamente, criando uma função que retorna uma tabela (não sei se PostgreSQl tem esse recurso), e dentro da função faz a `query` que retorna o suprimento, que depois para para o pivot esses dados,  mas da um bom trabalho, ate hoje não tive tempo pra fazer isso, usando oracle, mas fica a dica ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fiz um exemplo aqui, mas também não consegui informar de forma dinâmica a quantidade de colunas. Espero que ajude:

```
create table suprimentos (
codigo varchar(20),
modelo varchar(20));


insert into suprimentos (codigo,modelo) values ('50F0Z000','MS310');
insert into suprimentos (codigo,modelo) values ('50F0Z000','MS312');
insert into suprimentos (codigo,modelo) values ('50F0Z000','MS315');
insert into suprimentos (codigo,modelo) values ('50F0Z000','MS317');
insert into suprimentos (codigo,modelo) values ('50F0Z000','MS318');
insert into suprimentos (codigo,modelo) values ('50F0Z000','MS325');
insert into suprimentos (codigo,modelo) values ('50F0Z000','MS369');
insert into suprimentos (codigo,modelo) values ('50F0Z000','MS323');



  select * from crosstab(
'select codigo,''compativel'', modelo from suprimentos order by 1,2'::text
) as ct (codigo varchar, suprimento varchar, suprimento2 varchar)
```

**Edit:**

Conforme conversado no chat, não é necessário que todos os modelos venham em colunas separadas, sendo possível uma solução com arrays. Segue exemplo de código:

```
select codigo, array_agg(modelo) as compativeis from suprimentos group by codigo;
```

ou

```
select codigo, array_to_string(array_agg(modelo),' / ') as compativeis from suprimentos group by codigo;
```

Coloquei no SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/ced2f/4

Sua Query ficaria assim:

```
SELECT suprimento,
       array_to_string(array_agg(modelo),' / ') AS modelo
  FROM public.suprimento
      ,public.modelosuprimento
      ,public.impressoramodelo
 WHERE public.suprimento.codigo = public.modelosuprimento.codigosuprimento
   AND public.modelosuprimento.codigomodelo = public.impressoramodelo.codigo
   AND public.suprimento.codigo = 155
 GROUP BY suprimento
```

Comment: eu testei o seu exemplo e me foi exibido o seguinte erro: `ERROR:  function crosstab(text) does not exist
LINE 1: select * from crosstab(
                      ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
********** Error **********

ERROR: function crosstab(text) does not exist
SQL state: 42883
Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
Character: 15`

Comment: qual versão do banco está usando  ?

Comment: É Postgresql 9.6

Comment: tente executar o seguitne comando: `CREATE EXTENSION tablefunc`

Comment: Agora rodou, o problema é que assim como você comentou não consigo determinar de forma dinâmica a quantidade de colunas dai em si isso não resolve meu problema, mas obrigado pela ajuda +1

Comment: sim, mas pelo menos já dá uma luz, vou acompanhar a pergunta pra aprender também, vlw

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63230/discussion-between-r-santos-and-rovann-linhalis).

Comment: eu consigo colocar mais de dois itens no array? Por exemplo `array_to_string(array_agg(modelo),' / ',(codigomodelo)) AS modelo`

Comment: @R.Santos você pode concatenar as colunas antes de colocar no array, `array_to_string(array_agg(modelo || ',' || codigomodelo ),' / ') as modelo`

Comment: Perfeito @RovannLinhalis, muito obrigado

Comment: Ultima coisa, eu consigo determinar um `limit` para o array  ser exibido? para não ficar se repetindo? Ou daqui a pouco não permitir adicionar dados repetido no Array

Comment: Descobri como, usei isso `array_agg(distinct(..))`