# Resultado SQL em colunas

Tags: sql, oracle

Tenho uma consulta *Oracle SQL* que retorna os registos por linha, e eu queria transformar isso em coluna. Dei uma pesquisada e descobrir que o *Pivot* faz isso, mas não estou sabendo usá-lo, alguém pode me auxiliar?

**RETORNO ATUAL:**

```
SELECT
AFD.CODEMP AS CODEMP,
AFD.CODFUNC AS CODFUNC,
AFD.DTMOV,
AFD.HORA AS HORA,
OCO.DESCROCOR,
AFD.FECHADO
FROM
TFPAFDT AFD
LEFT JOIN TFPOCO OCO ON OCO.NUOCOR = AFD.NUOCOR 
WHERE
AFD.CODEMP = 1 
AND AFD.CODFUNC = 702 
AND (
    ( AFD.DTMOV BETWEEN TO_DATE ( '01/08/2017', 'DD-MM-YYYY' ) AND TO_DATE ( '30/08/2017', 'DD-MM-YYYY' ) ) 
    OR ( AFD.DTINIJORNADA BETWEEN TO_DATE ( '01/08/2017', 'DD-MM-YYYY' ) AND TO_DATE ( '30/08/2017', 'DD-MM-YYYY' ) ) 
)
```

[image: RESULTADO DO RETORNO ATUAL]

**RETORNO ESPERADO:**

Eu gostaria que as linhas do retorno viessem a data do movimento e as horas de marcação como coluna, conforme exemplo abaixo.

```
Dt. Mov.   | Dt1 | Dt 2 | Dt 3 | Dt 4<br>
23/08/2017 | 800 | 1206 | 1311 | 1802
```

Comment: Qual a necessidade disso? Caso seja apenas um modo de visualizar os retornos da uma olhada aqui https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/225916/retorno-de-comando-sql

Comment: @R.Santos Eu preciso de cada registro de 'Hora' em uma coluna, da forma de string_agg (oracle), ele traz todos os registros e uma coluna apenas. Obrigado.

Comment: Tem algum campo que indique que o tipo da entrada/saída , ou é apenas a posição , sendo a posição uma sequencia artificial poderia ser criada por "analytic functions" .

Comment: @Motta tem sim! Existe uma coluna com as informações 'E (entrada)' e 'S (saída)'.

Comment: Ainda complica pois são duas tags para quarto marcações , fora as marcações do pessoal que vira a noite , vigias , callcenters etc, já usou analytic functions ?

Comment: @Motta Além da coluna 'E' e 'S' eu tenho outra coluna com a informação de '1' e '2' para indicar o primeiro turno e o segundo turno. Quanto as marcações de virar a noite e etc, não existe no meu cenário.

Comment: O sql de pivot parece ser simples então , amanhã , se tiver tempo , eu posto algo.

Comment: @Motta ok, fico no aguardo. Agradeço desde já.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65910/discussion-between-tiago-martins-and-motta).

Answer (score 0):

--uma solução com CASE e MAX
--o case faz o pivot e o max para garantir em apenas uma linha
--supondo os nomes das colunas

```
SELECT
AFD.CODEMP AS CODEMP,
AFD.CODFUNC AS CODFUNC,
AFD.DTMOV,
max(case when turno = 1 and tipo = 'E' then AFD.HORA else null end) hr1,
max(case when turno = 1 and tipo = 'S' then AFD.HORA else null end) hr2,
max(case when turno = 2 and tipo = 'E' then AFD.HORA else null end) hr3,
max(case when turno = 2 and tipo = 'S' then AFD.HORA else null end) hr4
FROM
TFPAFDT AFD
LEFT JOIN TFPOCO OCO ON OCO.NUOCOR = AFD.NUOCOR 
WHERE
AFD.CODEMP = 1 
AND AFD.CODFUNC = 702 
AND (
    ( AFD.DTMOV BETWEEN TO_DATE ( '01/08/2017', 'DD-MM-YYYY' ) AND TO_DATE ( '30/08/2017', 'DD-MM-YYYY' ) ) 
    OR ( AFD.DTINIJORNADA BETWEEN TO_DATE ( '01/08/2017', 'DD-MM-YYYY' ) AND TO_DATE ( '30/08/2017', 'DD-MM-YYYY' ) ) 
)
group by AFD.CODEMP,
         AFD.CODFUNC,
         AFD.DTMOV
```

Comment: funcionou, mas nos casos que possuem registro de ocorrência ele duplica o dado o registro (a data). O certo seria para cada período, uma coluna que informe a ocorrência, caso exista, ou deixar em branco, caso null.

Comment: O que seria "registro de ocorrência" ?

Comment: ocorrência (justificativa) caso o colaborador não registre algum ponto.

Comment: vai ficar null , esta "ocorrencia" é outra tabela

Answer (score 0):

[Aqui](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_converting_rows_columns.htm) encontrei vários exemplos com o que procuras fazer. Penso que o mais simples é usando a função LISTAGG, mas agrupa toda a informação em uma coluna. Verifica o link caso isto não seja o que pretendas.

Código:

```
SELECT AFD.DTMOV,
LISTAGG (AFD.HORA, ',') 
WITHIN GROUP 
(ORDER BY AFD.HORA) Horas
FROM TFPAFDT AFD
GROUP BY AFD.DTMOV
```

Comment: Também é uma solução mas não "coluna"